# Could an average person properly live out of a 3x3(bodylength) cabin/house?

Tags: humanoid, architecture, daily-life

So I figured that, yes, a tiny person living in a normal size home would need or at least greatly benefit from their own house or hideyhole.

But with that out of the way, I wanted to figure how small of a living space I can get away with without making it virtually a jailcell/holding cell.

The reason being is while the homeowner kinda knows he is there, the little person does not really want to reveal himself, not fully, like in *The Borrowers*. A big house would be too obvious. So this rules out something like a dollhouse(too big) or shoebox(too small).

So what something 3 bodylengths(he is 6 inchs tall so 18 inches) long and wide, so kinda pizzaboxish in area. For height, I figure 7 inches would be tall enough for the celling.

Would this be large enough to live in properly?

For context, this 'Lilliputian' is male, 30ish, and in good/average health. Again, he is 6 inches tall(do not bring up negative effects caused by Square-Cube Law). The cabin/house/box is 18 inches long and wide, and 7 inches tall. And by live properly I mean can he cook, sleep, bathe, entertain, store, and 'empty' himself within the confines of this structure?

Comment: How is he disposing of waste?

Comment: Trashcan or bag. He empty on his outings for supplies and whatnot. @Kilisi

Comment: What does "properly" mean here?

Comment: Humans have been living in tiny huts for all of history. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hut#Traditional You could look up traditional living standards and go from there.

Comment: If you think of a "house" simply as a place to sleep and not a place to do everything one could fancy doing under a roof, then minimal space is sufficient. Many homes were just that and all the other activities, cook, eat, work, etc., were done elsewhere.

Comment: Sure. I lived in a 25sqm studio as a student, and while the bathroom was separate, it was generally perceived as rather spacious when I had guests. I've also lived in a 14sqm room for half a year, and while again kitchen and bath were separate, it was fine.

Comment: -1 for not researching the size of a [tiny house](https://www.tinyhouse.com/) and discerning if scaling it down to the size of a lilliputian wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I concur with JBH (downvote). Have you tried a [cross-multiplication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication) between what you think is "properly" for you and reducing it to the size of a tiny one? (N.B. : There was also voting to close for lacking details, but I missed your last paragraph's details about the resident's needs ^^".)

Comment: a space being a holding cell or jailcell is not based on its size, it is its function and the ideas asociated with the space that makes it as such, people often volunterily go into a space even smaller then a holding cell and enjoy their stay there- that being the shower, 

meanwhile, even if the room is the size of a mansion, but still empty and barren, then itd still give off the vibes of a holding cell. its the context that makes a space "feel" a certain way.

Comment: We can go even smaller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van-dwelling as long you skip the whole "bathing" thing. ☠️

Comment: @SurpriseDog Some vans actually have showers. You just need to get outside to use them. And refuel in water quite frequently. And accept it's going to be colder than a trip to Antarctica ❄️☠️.

Answer (score 8):

People live in tiny spaces all the time. I personally while in a hostel lived in a room that was less than twice my body length for a year. And the width was less than my body length. Microwave and little fridge on a shelf and it was comfortable enough.

[In this link there are people living in 4 square feet of space long term.](https://www.dylanhoffman.com/blog/2017/5/4/the-worlds-10-smallest-apartments)
There are also people who live in spaces they can't stand up in, basically just enough to sit up on their bed and shelves for everything.

Answer (score 5):

Of course.

For a human 1.7 meters tall, that would mean about 25 square meters, about 300 square foot. Both a kitchen and a toilet/sink/shower cubicle are possible in 2.5 square meters, leaving 20 for the living and sleeping areas. There is even space for a working desk. Your height is a bit low. People will want rooms where they *cannot* touch the ceiling even if they are stretching themselves. Think of the movements when one is getting into a sweater.

(Note that I'm assuming properly scaled furniture and appliances will be available. You won't easily get fridges 3 cm by 3 cm by 3 cm, or dishwashers of that size. Even the thickness of interior partitions might not scale well.)

Consider:

- [Prison cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_cell) (see the Red Cross recommendations in the second paragraph, and the US practice further down).
- [Army barracks](https://ec.militarytimes.com/benefits-handbook/housing/base-housing/) (but note that they do not *work* in there).
- [Tiny homes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny-house_movement#Size_of_homes).

Answer (score 3):

Think its a matter of design, ive been in microapartments in shenzheng, where the inhabitats room is pretty much the footprint of the bed, the shower and bathroom with the kitchen were a corrdior space shared with 5 other people.

so here the game is believablity, make a list of what would be needed in the room, and then play around with the space, start off with as small as possible, and based on what is needed inside, think of how it can all fit inside, if it doesnt, the increase the size of the blueprint a bit and try again.

you might also want to consider that there wont be a bathroom, since if the guy is living, what is bascially, in the walls of someone elses house, there wont be plumming solutions to house a toilet, so here you can look into portal toilets used by campers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_toilet

Id also recommend just going on youtube ad looking up microapartment tours,

Comment: I believe most huge cities have people living in extremely limited space. It's common in London and Paris to have tiny but treasured 6-7m² flats, for instance. Every meter is worth at least 70 €/£ a month there, after all :/...

Answer (score 2):

I am about 5 feet 9 inches tall.  I can reach about 8 feet high I guess and have an arm span over 6 feet.  At the present time I live with one other person in an apartment which has about 600 square feet and so about 300 square feet per person - when a third person lived here it was about 200 square feet per person.

I use the common areas like the kitchen and the bathroom, but I spend most of my time in my bedroom which is about 9 by 11 feet or 8 by 12 feet or something.  Approximately 100 square feet, I guess.

The house my family once lived in is now for sale, and the real estate sites say it has 2,590 square feet.  Between 3 and 10 members of my family lived in it at various times, making about 259 to 863.333 square feet per person.

If your little man is six inches tall and that is roughly equivalent to 6 feet for a human, then an inch is equivalent to a foot for him.  So a living area 18x 18 inches would be 324 square inches and equivalent to 324 square feet to a human.

If the little person wants to hide, he might live inside hollow walls and have an area about 2 or 3 inches by 5 feet or 60 inches and have 120 to 180 square inches, or the equivalent of about that many square feet for a human.

So I sort of envy him having more room than me, although having functional appliances my sizes is a plus for me.

You might be interested in *The Man in the Walls* (1963) by William Tenn.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/51122/51122-h/51122-h.htm